# Cannot telnet SQL Server port 1433

Tags: sql-server

I have Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise installed on it.

I disabled the Windows firewall and I'm sure that there isn't another firewall.

I cannot telnet my server.

I enabled TCP/IP, named pipes etc. in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and restarted everything.

By the way I can telnet locally, the problem is telnet via the network.

Any idea why I cannot telnet?

Comment: which are you using to locate your SQL server over network? windows host name? ip address? sql named instance?

Comment: Are you sure you have network connectivity from remote machine to your server (i.e. no routers/firewalls between two machines)? Have you tried using diagnostic tools (traceroute, tcpdump/wireshark etc.) to see what happened with your packets? Can you telnet any other port?

Comment: It's not really recommended to disable the firewall entirely; instead, create a firewall allow rule for the SQL Server service. You really have to wrangle with the firewall settings to actually turn it off *completely*, so this may still be the problem.

Comment: Do you have a non default port #?  Is it a named instance or the default MSSQLServer instance?  Also does your connection string put in a port # and do you go through any extra ACLs that the web servers might not?

Comment: Any update for us?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a powershell script I wrote for checking connectivity to SQL servers as you are using the default port (1433) all you need to do is pass in the server name.  If the connection fails the exception should give you a clue as to why.

e.g. 
`CheckSql.ps1 server\instance`

**CheckSql.ps1**

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$serverInstance);

$connectionString = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=true;Application Name=CheckSQL.ps1" -f $serverInstance;
$sqlConn = new-object("Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection") $connectionString;

Write-Host $connectionString

try {
    $sqlConn.Open();
    $sqlConn.Close();
    Write-Host "Connected OK"-foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor green
}
catch { 
    Write-Host $_ -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor red
}
finally { 
    $sqlConn.Dispose(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to connect with IP address(I can connect with MSSMS with this IP address in my server locally). And I can connect to my server via RDP, there are lots of websites that connecting to sql server and everything works fine.
The only problem is remote connection.

I can telnet with 80,110 port remotely but cannot with 1433 port.
And 1433 port is opened in firewall.

I will try wireshark, it's a good idea. And will write the results.